# How can I check if two graphs with LABELED vertices are isomorphic?

Tags: graph, isomorphism

For example, suppose I had a graph G that had all blue nodes and one red node. I also had a graph F that had all blue and one red node.

What is an algorithm that I can run to verify that these two graphs are isomorphic with respect to their colored nodes?

Answer (score 2):

I have made a few attempts at trying to create a polynomial graph isomorphism algorithm, and while I have yet to create an algorithm that is proven to be polynomial for every case, one algorithm I came up with is particularly suited for this purpose.  It's based on a DFA minimization algorithm (the specific algorithm is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization#Hopcroft.27s_algorithm ; you may want to find a description from elsewhere, since Wikipedia's is difficult to follow).

The original algorithm was initialized by organizing the vertexes into distinct groups based on degree (one group for vertexes of degree 1, one for vertexes of degree 2, etc.).  For your purposes, you will want to organize the vertexes into groups based upon both degree and label; this will ensure that no two nodes will be paired if they have different labels.  Each graph should have its own structure containing such groups.  Check the collection of groups for both graphs; there should be the same number of groups for the two graphs, and for each group in one graph, there should be a group in the other graph containing the same number of vertexes of the same degree and label.  If this isn't the case, the graphs aren't isomorphic.

At each iteration of the main algorithm, you should generate a new data structure for each of the two graphs for the vertex groups that the next step will use.  For each group, generate a list for each vertex of group indices/IDs that correspond to the vertexes that are adjacent to the vertex in question (include duplicate groups in this list).  Check each group to see if the sorted group index/ID list for each contained vertex is the same.  If this is the case, create a unmodified copy of this group in the next step's group structure.  If this isn't the case, then for each unique list of group indices/IDs within that group, create a new group for vertexes within the original group that generated that list and add this new group to the next step's group structure.  If you do not subdivide any of the groups of either graph in a given iteration, stop running the main portion of this algorithm.  If you subdivide at least one group, you will need to once again check to make sure the group structures of the two graphs correspond to each other.  This check will be similar to the one performed at the end of the algorithm's initialization (you may even be able to use the same function for both).  If this check fails, then the graphs aren't isomorphic.  If the check passes, then discard/free the current group structures and start the next iteration with the freshly created ones.

To make the process of determining "corresponding groups" easier, I would highly recommend using a predictable scheme for adding groups to the structure.  For example, if you add groups during initialization in (degree, label) order, subdivide groups in ascending index order, and add subdivided groups to the new structure based on the order of the group index list (i.e., sorted by first listed index, then second, etc.), then corresponding groups between the two group structures will always have the same index, which makes the process of keeping track of which groups correspond to each other *much* easier.

If all groups contain 3 or fewer vertexes when the algorithm completes, then the graphs are isomorphic (for corresponding groups containing 2 or 3 vertexes, any vertex pairing is valid).  If this isn't the case (this always happens for graphs where all nodes have equal degree and label, and sometimes happens for subgraphs with that property), then the graphs are not yet determined to be isomorphic or non-isomorphic.  To differentiate between the two cases, choose an arbitrary node of the first graph's largest group and separate it into its own group.  Then, for each node of the other graph's largest group, try running the algorithm again with that node separated into its own group.  In essence, you are choosing an unpaired node from the first graph and pairing it by guess-and-check to every node in the second graph that is still a plausible pairing.  If any of the forked iterations returns an isomorphism, the graphs are isomorphic.  If none of them do, the graphs are not isomorphic.

For general cases, this algorithm is polynomial.  In corner cases, the algorithm might be exponential.  Whether this is the case or not is related to how frequently the algorithm can be forced to fork in the worst case of both graph input and node selection, which I have had difficulties trying to put useful bounds on.  For example, although the algorithm forks at every step when comparing two full graphs, every branch of that tree produces an isomorphism; therefore, the algorithm returns in polynomial time in this case even though traversing the entire execution tree would require exponential time since traversing only one branch of the execution tree takes polynomial time.

Regardless, this algorithm should work well for your purposes.  I hope my explanation of it was comprehensible; if not, I can try providing examples of the algorithm handling simple cases or expressing it as pseudocode instead.

Answer (score 1):

Years ago, I created a simple and flexible algorithm for exactly this problem (graph isomorphism with labels).

I named it "Powerhash", and to create the algorithm it required two insights. The first is the power iteration graph algorithm, also used in PageRank. The second is the ability to replace power iteration's inside step function with anything that we want. I replaced it with a function that does the following on each iteration, and for each node:

- Sort the hashes (from previous iteration) of the node's neighbors
- Hash the concatenated sorted hashes
- Replace node's hash with newly computed hash

On the first step, a node's hash is affected by its direct neighbors. On the second step, a node's hash is affected by the neighborhood 2-hops away from it. On the Nth step a node's hash will be affected by the neighborhood N-hops around it. So you only need to continue running the Powerhash for N = graph_radius steps. In the end, the graph center node's hash will have been affected by the whole graph.

To produce the final hash, sort the final step's node hashes and concatenate them together. After that, you can compare the final hashes to find if two graphs are isomorphic. If you have labels, then add them (on the first iteration) in the internal hashes that you calculate for each node.

For more on this you can look at my post here:

https://plus.google.com/114866592715069940152/posts/fmBFhjhQcZF

The algorithm above was implemented inside the "madIS" functional relational database. You can find the source code of the algorithm here:

https://github.com/madgik/madis/blob/master/src/functions/aggregate/graph.py

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score -1):

Just checking; do you mean strict graph isomorphism or something else? Isomorphic graphs have the same adjacency relations (I.e. if node A is adjacent to node B in one graph then node g(A) is adjacent to node g(B) in another graph that is the result of applying the transformation g to the first one...) If you just wanted to check of one graph has the same types and number of nodes as another then you can just compare counts.

Comment: At any rate; this is a good starting point http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem

Comment: I've already looked at en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem . But thank you.